# Como aplico uma classe de estilo no componente InputText do C# Blazor?

Tags: html, c#, .net-core, blazor

Estou tentando criar uma classe de estilo no C# Blazor, mas a classe não encontra o CSS.

TechInputText.razor

```
<div class="container tech-input-text">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label>@Title</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <InputText class="input-text" placeholder="@Placeholder" @bind-Value="@Value" @bind-Value:after="OnCallback" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string Placeholder { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string Value { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> Callback { get; set; }

    private async Task OnCallback()
    {
        await Callback.InvokeAsync(Value);
    }
}
```

TechInputText.razor.css

```
.tech-input-text {
    text-align: initial;
}

.input-text {
    width: 100%;
    border: 4px solid #0e90e0 !important;
}
```

A classe de estilo tech-input-text está funcionando normalmente, mas a classe input-text não é encontrada.

Answer (score 0):

O Blazor segue uma convenção específica para localizar os arquivos de estilo associados a um componente. Os arquivos de estilo devem ter o mesmo nome que o componente Blazor, mas com a extensão `.razor.css` e devem estar na mesma pasta que o arquivo `.razor` do componente.

Certifique-se de que a estrutura de diretórios do seu projeto está organizada corretamente. O arquivo `TechInputText.razor.css` deve estar na mesma pasta que `TechInputText.razor`.

Por exemplo, a estrutura de diretórios pode ser assim:

```
Pages/
|-- TechInputText.razor
|-- TechInputText.razor.css
```

Se a estrutura de diretórios estiver correta e ainda assim o problema persistir, você pode tentar alguns passos de solução de problemas:

1. **Recarregue a Página:** Às vezes, alterações nos arquivos podem não ser detectadas imediatamente. Recarregue a página para garantir que as alterações entrem em vigor.
2. **Limpe o Cache do Navegador:** O cache do navegador pode reter versões antigas dos arquivos. Tente limpar o cache do navegador e recarregar a página.
3. **Verifique o Console do Navegador:** Abra as ferramentas de desenvolvedor do navegador (pressione F12 ou clique com o botão direito do mouse e escolha "Inspecionar" ou "Inspeção"). Verifique se há mensagens de erro no console que possam indicar problemas ao carregar o arquivo CSS.

Se após essas etapas o problema persistir, pode ser necessário examinar as configurações do seu projeto Blazor para garantir que ele esteja configurado corretamente para localizar os arquivos de estilo.